# Windows game bar stealing focus from games

Tags: windows-10

I've been having a few problems with windows game bar, specifically on games. The first is OSU! and the second is Minecraft.
Windows Game Bar keeps stealing focus from these apps and sending me to desktop. I used Windows Focus Logger to pinpoint the offending app.

The second issue I have is that it pops under in the background of OSU! and if I mouse over the area on the right hand side of the screen where it pops under, my cursor changes from the in-game cursor to the normal windows one and appears far from where I need to select a song.

My question is if there's a way to prevent the game bar from doing these things. I would still like to have it because I use it in games like Forza and Outer Worlds, so disabling it is not an option.

Comment: What is OSU? What do you mean exactly by stealing focus? Usually when I experience something similar to what you are describing, it is because I have hit a preconfigured key combination that pulls up an overlay, whether it is Steam or Microsoft or something else. Changing the shortcut keys or game mappings fixes that.

Comment: @JimDiroffII Osu is a rhythm game. That's not what's happening. Tell me that pressing 5 and 6 on the numpad over and over again warrants having your game minimizing completely. That's what happens. It takes over for a split second minimizing the game to desktop while you're playing. It can make you lose matches, die and detracts from the gameplay experience. Also Forza, I play with a controller, It does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Me too. I recently reinstalled Windows on 2 of my laptops due to storage upgrade. Now both of them have the Xbox Game Bar functionality broke focus on multiple games, including games like Forza Horizon 4. Strange enough, when I used it with Adobe XD to record the screen, it work just fine.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think using the app/game in windowed mode perhaps can be a workaround. For sure this is not the intended behavior of the Xbox Game Bar.

Comment: If you haven't tested your answer, and you aren't sure about your suggestion, then why don't you try it and update your answer with confirmed information?